Is sending out a paper copy of a survey to respondents an IRB violation?
I am part of a team that is trying to launch a third wave of a survey that was previously declared exempt by the IRB. I have two questions. First, do you think it would be a violation of institutional rules to send out a digital copy of the survey to respondents to review and then follow up with the link to the survey platform once it is approved by the IRB? Second, we realized after the fact that we are basically doing institutional research which is typically exempt from IRB but we already sent in the forms and it is under review. Is it okay or not okay to send it out if it is institutional research that won't be published/contribute to generalizable knowledge if we've already sent in the IRB forms?

There is likely someone at your institution who can answer these questions for you and following their instructions will CYA whereas asking the internet will not. As far as your institution's rules, that entirely depends on the institution and their rules.

You have two, unrelated questions here. Please focus on one.

if it is institutional research that won't be published/contribute to generalizable knowledge if we've already sent in the IRB forms -- there is some confusion here. You position is either: (1) this is internal research that does not require an IRB (this is possible, albeit rare on this site -- e.g., maybe you are a restaurant owner doing A/B testing on your website), or (2) this does require IRB approval/exemption. Which is it? In the former case, why have you sent in the IRB forms? In the latter case, what do you mean by "basically doing institutional research?"

@cag51, it is a survey of other institutions. Not our own institution. People will be filling it out albeit about their institution, not with personal information.

Fine, but my concern is that you seem to be going through the IRB approval/exemption process, but then in your last sentence, you imply that you don't actually need the IRB to be involved at all for what you're doing. You can't have it both ways: it's either one or the other.

You have to ask your IRB
No one here can tell you anything definitive, because we do not know the full context, and do not know your IRB's general policies.
